# MultiResolutionImage for Windows Phone 8.0 with screen resolution 1080p

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, screen-resolution

Hi I am developing Windows Phone 8.0 App for all resolution.
Now from the this link
[Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx)
there are 4 resolution for Windows Phone 8.0 .
I am using telerik control for displaying image so , from this link of telerik [Telerik UI for WindowsPhone : RadMultiResolutionImage](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/multiresolution-gettingstarted.html) says code like this

**Image.Screen-WVGA.png - the image that will be used for the WVGA resolution (480x800)
Image.Screen-720p.png - the image that will be used for the 720p resolution (720x1280)
Image.Screen-WXGA.png - the image that will be used for the WXGA resolution (768x1280)**

Now , there is no specification for resolution **1080 x 1920**  . I have tried **Image.Screen-1080p.png** but it is not working.

Please reply ,

Thank You.